# How to replace dashes with slashes in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, replace

I want to replace all the dashes from my PHP filenames but I don't know how to do it.

Basically I have something like this:

```
http://localhost/category-activity.php
```

And I want to end up with this:

```
http://localhost/category/activity
```

I also need that the script scans for ALL dashes meaning that if I have something like:

```
http://localhost/category-activity-subactivity.php
```

Ends up in something like:

```
http://localhost/category/activity/subactivity
```

I am already using the following code to remove the extension

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# not an existing directory and is a php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# make sure there are no slashes and doesn't already end with .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+/.+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php  [L]

# not an existing directory or file (this needs to take place so existing paths won't get / replaced with -
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1-$2   [L]
```

Mod-rewrite will continue to reapply rules until the URI doesn't get rewritten, so uri's like `/category/activity/subactivity` will continue to get rewritten until it goes through all the rules untouched.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't seem to get it working. I've made a link to a PHP file but the URL shows the full name + extension.I also tried tried to link without the extension or using slashes instead of dashes but it gets redirected to my index.php always.